# Mulilingual portal reset password notification email

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template, partner-portal, forgot-your-password

I implemented the logic to reset a partner portal user password from a visualforce page. The form successfully resets the partner user's password and sends an email using this code in the ResetPasswordController:

```
boolean success = Site.forgotPassword(Username);
```

An email is sent using the Lost Password Template accessible in the Partner Portal customization page.

I need to send the email in the portal user language. This it the email recipient and not the current user language. I need to select up to 10 languages. As there is only one email template setting available and as a part of the content of the email is generated automatically by the Site Member function, I am having difficulty sending it in other languages than english. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I received this Answer from Salesforce after submitting  a Case:

_I crossed checked with Tier3 and seniors and currently it is not possible. Please follow below Idea link for this-

[link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kuG1AAI)

Developer Support Engineer 
salesforce.com_